# Contents displayed in WP7 XNA game development ?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, xna-4.0

I have a problem when contents are displayed on the windows phone 7 emulator

If you tried to render any sprite and run the project .... the sprite is not in it's correct form but rotated clockwise .... moreover ... the emulator assumes that the coordinated (0 , 0) at the right upper most not the left upper most when the emulator is in portrait position , but when it's landscape ... it displays anything correct ... but if I need to make my game run in portrait and landscape ... Is that a flaw in the sdk ... or there is something that should be done ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can write this in your game constructor and it will come correctly..

```
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 800;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 480;
```